# argv vs bash expansion/command substitution/python

Tags: python, c, bash, argv

My apologies upfront if my terminology is somewhat off but I'm trying to figure out
why one thing works, and the other doesn't.
I've got this program,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]){
    printf("argc: %d\n", argc);
    if(argc != 10) {
        printf("argc incorrect\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(strcmp(argv[4],"\x00")) 
    {
        printf("argv[4] incorrect\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(strcmp(argv[5],"\x20\x0a\x0d")) 
    {
        printf("argv[5] incorrect\n");
        return 0;
    };
    printf("yes\n");    
}
```

I've been trying now for some time to pass the strcmp section by using a mix
of command and/or process substitution and python but I can't figure out
how to make this work, e.g.

```
./compartx $(python -c 'print("A " * 4)'; python -c 'print("\x00")'; python -c 'print("B " * 5)';)
```

[I'm trying to pass the first check for argv[4], nevermind the argv[5]
for the moment]

I do see the warning "command substitution ignored nullbyte in input". There's
numerous posts on the web suggesting it's impossible to pass on a nullbyte
to argv, but I went through the bash manual this morning, and I managed
to pass the strcmp section using this parameter

```
./compartx {0..2} $'\0' $' \n\r' {0..3}
```

Is there any way to achieve the same thing using python?

Cheers,
Sven

Comment: The `\x00` is bogus, it means empty string. You need to use interpolation for **only** argv[5] if you can't produce that otherwise. Also, this is bit of a nonsense question, if you use Python, then use it all the way and use `subprocess.run` to execute the command!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Technically, it means two `NUL`s in a row. But from `strcmp`'s perspective (which stops at the first `NUL`) they're equivalent.

Comment: `$'\0'` is doing nothing, the same `"\x00"`. You could just `''` in shell and `""` in C with same result.

Answer (score 2):

It does not even make sense to try to get these interpolated in the shell command line; and most probably it does not work in one interpolation anyway!

If you need to use Python to generate the arguments, then use Python to run the command too:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run([
    './compartx',
    '1', '2', '3',
    # strcmp will stop at the first null byte, so empty string will do here
    '', 
    '\x20\x0a\x0d',
    '6', '7', '8', '9'
])
```

run it and you get

```
argc: 10
yes
```

Comment: I don't *have* use Python, and why would it not make sense? The shell command does work afterall, whereas the print in Python does not. Using subprocess  to mimic the shell command is interesting so cheers for that, but it's missing the point.

Comment: @sven: The `print` in Python works. You just passed it along via the shell in a way that doesn't work. You're mixing back and forth in a way that obscures the source of the problem.

Comment: Ok I assume that's what the warning wants to tell me.

Comment: @sven it is much easier to do *actual* attacks in Python than in Bash, say.

Comment: I'm not blaming Python just my own ignorance :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to send the `NUL`; just pass the empty string. `strcmp` stops at a `NUL` byte anyway, and the empty string in C is just a `NUL`; passing an extra `NUL` explicitly doesn't change behavior (it hits the first one and stops).

Comment: Ok understood I didn't check with an empty string, cheers. Still, I'm reading argv[argc] is a null pointer, how is it that the shell expansion works, and the program evaluates argv beyond the null byte, and with python it doesn't (at least it doesn't for me).

Comment: @sven: It's not Python's fault, you just didn't output something the shell can parse. You've made yourself a really terrible bit of code that, between `NUL`-terminated C-strings and shell parsing idiosyncrasies, is really hard to get right (and there's no *reason* to do it, given you could pass `""` as the shell argument without invoking Python at all).

Comment: yes this not an attack on Python. I'm working on a challenge which I managed to passed by using the above shell command, so I'm a happy camper just trying to take away a few extras, thats the whole point after all.